# Use 1 class instance in multiples activities

Tags: android, performance, singleton

I created a class that uses 1 SOUNDPOOL to play musical notes. The problem is that there are a lot of notes and thus loading takes too long. I'd like to know if it was possible to use a single instance of the class in several activities to avoid having to recreate my music player each time.

Comment: Make this class singleton

Answer (score 0):

have you heard of Singleton Design Pattern? Have a look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). Following this design pattern will ensure you have ever created only one instance of the class and all other classes will reuse this only instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Singletone** design pattern

```
public class ClassicSingleton {
   private static ClassicSingleton instance = null;
   protected ClassicSingleton() {
      // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
   }
   public static ClassicSingleton getInstance() {
      if(instance == null) {
         instance = new ClassicSingleton();
      }
      return instance;
   }
}
```

Comment: You welcome. But please remember if you want to use this Singletone class from different thread please use thread safe Singletone: http://crunchify.com/thread-safe-and-a-fast-singleton-implementation-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

As the other said, use Singleton. In fact, Android provides a Singleton object already, which is the Application. You may want to use that.